# Creating a hyperlink within a popup using Leaflet.JS

Tags: leaflet

I have been struggling to use Leaflet (just getting back into coding) and I have done everything I would like to do but add a hyperlink to a pop-up on my map. The current code is:

```
var marker = L.marker([46.423611, -86.624417], {
        title: "This is a test" ,
      }).addTo(map)
      .bindPopup("<h1> Test Title </h1> <img src=' Link to Image' width='100' height='100' />");
```

I would like to hyperlink 'Test Title' but each time I try using basic HTML I cannot seem to get it to work. Just a basic hyperlink to a webpage. I would also like to hyperlink the image, but I would stop at just the text for now to save time on this project!

Comment: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/a

Answer (score 6):

Use this way:

```
var marker = L.marker([46.423611, -86.624417], {
    title: "This is a test" ,
}).addTo(map)
  .bindPopup('<a href="Web Page Adress Here"><h1> Test Title </h1></a><img src="Link to Image" width=100 height=100 />');
```

[image]

To add the same hyperlink to the image use this:

```
'<a href="Web Page Adress Here"><h1> Test Title </h1><img src="Link to Image" width=100 height=100 /></a>'
```